# Aptana Studio 3 Not Showing Themes

Tags: aptana, aptana3

So I recently moved all of the files that I want to keep onto a secondary hard drive in my laptop. This also included the workspace I use for Aptana Studio 3. As a result, there was a particular file that I had to delete and let the program recreate just to get the program to start up as well as re-import the projects I was working with.

The issue now, though, is that I cannot change or even bring up the themes in the preferences editor. When I first go to Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes, I get a message that reads:

> The currently displayed page contains invalid values.

and doesn't show anything. On the rare occurrences that I AM able to get that particular window to show up, there's nothing there except an empty drop down menu. Anyone have any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks.

*P.S. YES, I have Googled it and hence, since I didn't find anything, I'm asking the question here.*

Comment: Any news on this? I am facing this right now and so far I've been unable to find a way to completely reset the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

got this answer from another post...

I got the same problem. After updating Aptana to 3.5, whenever I looked at the themes settings, it crashed down saying.

"the currently displayed page contains invalid values"
Probably the new update has its own bugs for some reason.

the only way to fix the problem is to downgrade the version of Aptana studio.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version#RevertingtoaPreviousVersion-AptanaStudio3.4.1

just Download 3.4.1 version and all things gonna be ok.

Answer (score -2):

Add Eclipse Themes from http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

Details to add themes on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797588/aptana-studio-3-build-3-5-0-201312191422-theme-the-currently-displayed-page) post.

Edit: This does not seem to work :( only the bg changes. I never noticed that the font colors never changed. Have to wait for patches I guess. Don't want to downgrade though :-|

Comment: It does not work. 
This is the version of my aptana studio. 
"Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201312191422"

Comment: Tried solution, no joy.