# Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201312191422 theme - the currently displayed page contains invalid values

Tags: themes, aptana, preferences

What shall I do?

[image]
I just updated Aptana and now the Theme part of the Preferences is not working anymore. Anybody with idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. After updating Aptana to 3.5, 
whenever I looked at the themes settings, it crashed down saying.

```
"the currently displayed page contains invalid values"
```

Probably the new update has its own bugs for some reason.

the only way to fix the problem is to downgrade the version of Aptana studio.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version#RevertingtoaPreviousVersion-AptanaStudio3.4.1

just Download 3.4.1 version and all things gonna be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio got updated today to build: 3.5.0.201312191422 and then I lost all the built in themes. But hey, I could install Eclipe Theme from http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

The procedure to add themes is:

Help > Install New Software > Add > {type some name e.g. Eclipse Color Themes} in Name box and add this link in the location box: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/ > Click OK.

[image: Add Eclipse Color Theme]

You should be able to see the plugin load. Click the check box > Next > Restart. You should be able to see the Themes in Preference > {search theme} > General > Appearance > Color Theme

=====

## Edit: Update to Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201401092130 to fix issue

Finally updated to Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201401092130. Now default Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes work! I still miss the icons to change themes from the main interface.

Eclipse themes does not work still, you may uninstall the plugin.

Comment: While this plugin certainly rocks, it's not the solution here: After installing it and trying to set a theme, only the background color of the editor is changed, nothing else. It looks like Aptana has seriously effed up their build (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.5.0.201312191422).

Comment: You may want to downgrade until a new version is out: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version

Comment: You are right, only the bg changes. I never noticed that the font colors never changed. Have to wait for patches I guess. Don't want to downgrade though :-|